# How does one pass email validation data to a MySQL server using Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, email, ngmodel

I was able to make a CRUD app with SpringBoot and MySQL Server, but it didn't have email validation, so I could just send any kind of text using this in the employee component.html

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                Last Name </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailId" required [(ngModel)]="employee.emailId" name="emailId">
        </div>
```

However now that I've included validation, I had to switch out ngModel for formControlName in this code

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                    Email Id </label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required formControlName="email" name="email">

                <form [formGroup]="loginForm">
                    <div class="invalid" *ngIf="loginForm.controls['email']?.invalid && (loginForm.controls['email'].dirty || loginForm.controls['email'].touched)">

                        <div class="font-style8" *ngIf="loginForm.controls['email'].errors?.['required']">

                            This field is required.

                        </div>
                        <div class="font-style8" *ngIf="loginForm.controls['email'].errors?.['email']">
                            Please enter an email in this field.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
</div>
</form>
```

And it comes with this in the typescript file

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm=this.fb.group({
      email:['',[Validators.required, Validators.email]]
      
    })
  }
```

So I'm trying to figure out how to transfer the email data to the Employee.emailId using a function. Looking up for ways, I came across setValue, but not sure how to implement it, if that is the best method.

Answer (score 0):

FormControl is the best way to validate input values.
Why u use 2 formgroup? With 1 is enough.
You can subscribe to the changes of the control value, for that u need to write:

```
this.loginForm.get('email').valueChanges (changes => {...Your function})
```

Only if you need the value in "real time", if you dont, u can use

```
Employee.emailId = this.loginForm.get('email').value when u need it.
```